# sqoop export fail through oozie

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I am trying to export data to `mysq`l from `hdfs` through `sqoop`. I am able to run sqoop through shell and it is working fine . but when I am invoking through `oozie`. it is arising following error and getting fail. I have also included jars. there is no desciptive log

sqoop script:

```
export  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/bigdata --username root --password cloudera --verbose --table AGGREGATED_METRICS --input-fields-terminated-by '\0001' --export-dir /bigdata/aggregated_metrics
```

error:

```
Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
```

Comment: Our issue was HiveServer2, so the sqoop CLI uses Hiveserver1 not 2. oozie sqoop uses HiveServer2, so our LDAP was not setup on the HiveServer2 servers...this created an issue where the job runs but throws this error and does not load the data in hive. Check your Hive Metastore log

Answer (score 2):

The erros you see in Oozie usually do not provide much details. To get more info about what went wrong you can take the job_id from the Oozie action and search for it in the JobTracker logs. There you will find a more detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to install Sqoop jars with all dependencies into Oozie (either to shared directories or to your particular workflow).

Comment: Hi @jarek I have been facing the same issue with no luck whatsoever. I have added sqoop jars in time stamped share oozie lib and jdbc drivers too still facing the same issue. Can you point out exactly what other jars are needed to be added to the shared library other than the ones which are there in oozie/share/lib/ directory in the oozie installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  This problem went aways when I added the mysql-connector-java.jar library into the lib directory located inside the oozie project root directory where the job.properties and workflow.xml files are located.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Adding mysql-connector-java-*.jar to workflow lib directory solves the problem.
But its hard to copy the jar for each sqoop job.

Adding the mysql-connector-java-*.jar once to share/lib/sqoop directory in HDFS is better.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not detail enough here.
One another thing is, in the workflow sqoop action, could try to use

```
\0001
```

instead of

```
'\0001'
```